# Rails router returns 404, but route and records exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Ruby on Rails API ( Rails 5.0.6 ). I have defined a namespaced route like the following:

```
namespace :api do
  resources :users
end
```

I am sending a get request to the API:

```
my.domain.com/api/users/1
```

And sometimes the response is 404, sometimes it serves the User with ID 1. I have not found anything that would suggest a possible reason/suggestion on this matter. Has anyone experienced this before?

Any suggestions? I am a Rails Developer for more that 6 years and I have deployed numerous applications and never stumbled upon this behaviour...

Comment: How do you retrieve the User in the controller?

Comment: User.find(params[:id]). When I get the 404 error, the request never reaches the controller. It is returned from the router, as if the route is not found

Comment: Thanks! Do you have the generated SQL request for when the User is not found?

Comment: Since it is not reaching the controller, the query is not executed at all.

Comment: Are you getting a 404 or a routing error when it fails? What happens when you `User.find(params[:id])` in the rails console?

Comment: can you add the code for your controller and application controller as well?

Comment: Maybe try to verify the Api path in the controller like `class Api::UsersController < Api::ApiController`

Comment: @nflauria It returns the user as expected

Comment: @JamesRusso user = User.find(params[:id]) and in a new line, render json: user